# SQL Server 2008 R2: BCP 0 rows copied

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to use SQL Server 2008 R2 `BCP` command to import a file from a command prompt. It returns only the first row in the text file.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SeanTest]
(
    [name] [varchar](3000) NULL,
    [score] [decimal](28, 10) NULL,
    [mdwtag_rawfile] [varchar](3000) NULL,
    [mdwtag_asdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [mdwtag_rid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [mdwtag_acquiretime] [bigint] NULL
)
```

DataSource (tab-separated) `datafilesrc.txt`:

```
sean y  1.2 myfilename1.csv 2021-08-25 00:00:00 1   1000
mike h  3.4 myfilename2.csv 2021-08-20T01:02:03 2   2000
```

Command Prompt:

```
bcp DLTI.dbo.SeanTest IN C:\Temp\SeanYang\datafilesrc.txt -V100 -c -S [server] -U [user] -P [password] -e C:\temp\mherr.txt
```

Comment: That format file really doesn't look right: you have no length prefixes so they shouldn't be specified, the data type should be `SQLCHAR` for all of them because the number and date columns are not in the native byte format, the separators should be `\t` for all except the last which should be `\r\n`

Comment: I was originally trying to not use a file format but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: OK but your format file is wrong as mentioned, also your `bcp` command should have `-c` not `-N`

Comment: That worked but now it is only reading the first line

Comment: `That worked` what worked? Did you change the format file, or the command, please update your question

Comment: I changed the -n to -c and dropped the file format and that made it so it read the file but it only copied in the first row.

Comment: Then you also need to specify `-r \n -t \t`